# Check if ViewController was opened with a QuickAction

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

how can I check if my Swift App was opened with a QuickAction? I search for a solution which can be inside of viewDidLoad.

e.g.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      if *VC was opened with a QuickAction* == true {
          // do this
       else {
          // do sth else
       }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the application is opened through 3D touch following method in AppDelegate is called

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

//Navigate to required viewController from here
//YourViewController.isOpenedThrough3DTouch = true
}
```

You can create a base class for all your ViewControllers and declare a bool variable `isOpenedThrough3DTouch`

Set this variable to true inside the `AppDelegate` Callback where the navigation to required `ViewController` is initiated, So your `viewDidLoad` knows